# how to pass imageButton and drawable file in function inside a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, imagebutton

is it possible to pass imagebutton and drawable file ( image ) as a function parameter inside a fragment
i have done this but it is showing error

```
fun def(right :Drawable , x:ImageButton){
            val bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.right)
            val rounded=RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources,bitmap)
            rounded.isCircular=true
            val image = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.x) as ImageButton
            image.setImageDrawable(rounded)

        }
```

Comment: Instead of creating image variable go with x.setImageDrawable since x is imagebutton already ?

Comment: x.setImageDrawable does not work inside fragments

Comment: How? Since image works and types are the same

Comment: Show the error message

Comment: what to do for drawable , it is not recognizing  the "right" parameter

Answer (score 0):

As @P.Juni suggests, try to use `imageButton.setImageDrawable`

But if you insist to send button and the drawable into the function you can do like this.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton);
    def(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, imageButton);
}

fun def(drawableId: Int, imageButton: ImageButton){
    val bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, drawableId)
    val rounded= RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources,bitmap)
    rounded.isCircular=true
    imageButton.setImageDrawable(rounded)
}
```

Comment: but when i am calling def function it is not able to recognize the drawable parameter

Answer (score 0):

Actually `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` requires resources and drawableId

also `root.findViewById<View>` requires layoutId

so you can change your function to this

```
fun def(drawableId: Int, layoutId: Int) {
    val bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, drawableId)
    val rounded=RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources,bitmap)
    rounded.isCircular=true
    val image = root.findViewById<View>(layoutId) as ImageButton
    image.setImageDrawable(rounded)
}
```